# В каком прокси возможна модификация страниц, проходящих через него?

Tags: squid, html, proxy

Например чтобы можно было вставлять в каждую запрашиваемую страницу баннер?

Comment: Гораздо более интересной фичей было бы удаление баннеров :)

Comment: http://www.proxomitron.ru/ но это больше чтоб резать баннеры ))

Answer (score 2):

В squid есть поддержка протокола [ICAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Content_Adaptation_Protocol).

- [Content Adaptation](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation)
- [Feature: ICAP (Internet Content Adaptation Protocol)](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ICAP)
- [A Python based ICAP server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icap-server/)